# What is the correct way to format my code?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

1. I have been trying to resolve my script with no results. I can't get
   the load data to display. It is saving in members.txt and can read
   it manually if opened. If someone can give any other advice on the
   script as a whole it would be greatly appreciated.

   I have reasearced greatly changed script around still have no luck.

   import os    if '**file**' in vars():
          wk_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath('**file**'))    else:
          print('We are running the script interactively')
          class playerCLass(object):
          name = ""
          phone = ""
          number = 0

   ```
      def __init__(self, name, phone, number):
          self.name = name
          self.phone = phone
          self.number = number


      def setname(self, name):
          self.name = name


       def setphone(self, phone):
           self.phone = phone

       def setnumber(self, number):
           self.number = number

       def getname(self):
           return self.name

       def getphone(self):
           return self.phone

       def getnumber(self):
           return self.number

       def display_data(self):
           print("")
           print("Member information: ")
           print("Name:", self.name)
           print("Phone number:", self.phone)
           print("Jersey number:", self.number)


   def displayMenu():
       print("===========Menu Selections===========")
       print("1. Display Team Roster.")
       print("2. Add Member.")
       print("3. Remove Member.")
       print("4. Edit Member.")
       print("5. Save Data.")
       print("6. Load Data.")
       print("9. Exit Program.")
       print("")
       return int(input("<<Selection>> "))


   def printPlayer(players):
       print("Current members: ")
       if len(players) == 0:
           print("No current members in memory.")
       else:
           x = 1
           while x < len(players):
               print(x)
               x = x + 1


   def addPlayer(players):
       newName = input("Type in member's name to be added to the roster:")
       newPhone = input("Type in the member's phone number:")
       newNumber = int(input("Type in the member's jersey number:"))
       players[newName] = playerCLass(newName, newPhone, newNumber)
       return players


   def removePlayer(players):
       name = input("Enter member's name to be removed:")
       if name in players:
           del players[name]
       else:
           print("member's name not found in list: ")
       return players


   def editPlayer(players):
       oldName = input("Enter the name you want to edit: ")
       if oldName in players:
           newName = input("Enter a new name: ")
           newPhone = input("Enter new phone number: ")
           newNumber = int(input("Enter new jersey number: "))
           players[oldName] = playerCLass(newName, newPhone, newNumber)
       else:
           print("No such name in memory: ")
       return players


   def saveData():
       filename = input("Filename to save: ")
       print("Saving data...")
       outFile = open(filename, "wt")
       for x in players.keys():
           name = players[int(x)].getname()
           phone = players[int(x)].getphone()
           number = str(players[x].getnumber())
           outFile.write(name + "," + phone + "," + number +  "\n")
       print("Data saved.")
       outFile.close()


   def loadData():
       players = {}
       filename = input("Filename to load: ")
       inFile = open(filename, "rt")
       print("Loading data...")
       while True:
           inLine = inFile.readline()
           if not inLine:
               break
           inLine = inLine[:-1]
           name, phone, number = inLine.split(",")
           players[name] = (name, phone, number)
       print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
       inFile.close()
       return players


   print("Welcome to the Team Manager")
   players = {}
   menuSelection = displayMenu()
   print()
   while menuSelection != 9:
       if menuSelection == 1:
           printPlayer(players)
       elif menuSelection == 2:
           players = addPlayer(players)
       elif menuSelection == 3:
           players = removePlayer(players)
       elif menuSelection == 4:
           players = editPlayer(players)
       elif menuSelection == 5:
           saveData()
       elif menuSelection == 6:
           loadData()
       menuSelection = displayMenu()

   print("Exiting Program...")
   ```

Comment: did you try checking the code in your `loadData` function? like putting `print("Executing read file")` before `if not inLine` or adding `print("file not read")` inside this if-block or just `print(inLine)`, because it seems that that function is where you are having trouble with

Comment: Yes still no luck yet resolving the issue

Comment: so what is the output when you do `print(inLine)` inside the `if not inLine:` block?

Comment: No players in memory

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is specifically not getting `printPlayer` to work you can do

```
def printPlayer(players):
    print("Current members: ")
    if len(players) == 0:
        print("No current members in memory.")
    #Iterate through dictionary of player name and player object and call
    #display data on each of them
    else:
        for name, player in players.items():
            print(player.display_data())
```

If you then run the code and input according to the statements you wrote, you should get something like this.

```
Welcome to the Team Manager
===========Menu Selections===========
1. Display Team Roster.
2. Add Member.
3. Remove Member.
4. Edit Member.
5. Save Data.
6. Load Data.
9. Exit Program.

<<Selection>> 1
Current members: 
No current members in memory.
===========Menu Selections===========
1. Display Team Roster.
2. Add Member.
3. Remove Member.
4. Edit Member.
5. Save Data.
6. Load Data.
9. Exit Program.

<<Selection>> 2
Type in member's name to be added to the roster:Joe
Type in the member's phone number:123
Type in the member's jersey number:456
===========Menu Selections===========
1. Display Team Roster.
2. Add Member.
3. Remove Member.
4. Edit Member.
5. Save Data.
6. Load Data.
9. Exit Program.

<<Selection>> 1
Current members: 

Member information: 
Name: Joe
Phone number: 123
Jersey number: 456
None
===========Menu Selections===========
1. Display Team Roster.
2. Add Member.
3. Remove Member.
4. Edit Member.
5. Save Data.
6. Load Data.
9. Exit Program.

<<Selection>>
```

Comment: I added the new script and still having the same issue...... It does not give me an error just simply states "No current members in memory."

Comment: Did you add members?

Comment: No I was trying to figure out excactly what I have to add. I have only been learning python  for two months. I appreciate all your help!!!

Comment: Okay I added a sample run I did, check it out

Comment: It still gives me the same issue. I can display what is added but after It is after I exit the program.If I load data and then display, states nothing in memory. I know it is saving for I manually opened membners.txt and the data is there. Also adding print command before inline does not resolve it.